# Is there a formal way to speed up the first-order logic proof of $\{\{a\}, \{a,0\}\} = \{\{b\}, \{b,0\}\} \iff a = b$, where $a,b \in \mathbb{N}$?

Tags: set-theory, first-order-logic

I'm working on axiomatic set theory and first-order logic, and I'm wondering if there is a formal theorem we could cite in order to speed up the mentioned proof (especially to speed up the analogous proof for induction on bigger ordered pairs). Is there a way to speed up the reference to the basic elements of each set? e.g., if we the above sets $A$ and $B$, is there a general or standardized function $F$ s.t. $F(A) = \{ a, 0 \}$ and $F(B) = \{b,0\}$, or maybe a syntactical argument that can quickly refer to the fact that $a$ and $b$ are different characters?

Otherwise, we have the following, rather long (even if informal) proof for a very simple fact:
Suppose $A=\{\{a\}, \{a,0\}\} = \{\{b\}, \{b,0\}\}=B$ and $a \neq b$
$$
\begin{array}{rcll}
A=B \iff \forall x(x \in A \iff x \in B) & (1) & (\text{premise, extensionality})\\
\{a\} \in A & (2) & (\text{premise})\\
\{a\} \in B & (3) & (\text{from 1, 2})\\
x \in B \iff x = \{b\} \lor x = \{b,0\} &(4) & (\text{premise})\\
\{a\} = \{b\} \lor \{a\} = \{b,0\} & (5) & (\text{from 3, 4})\\
\{a\} = \{ b\} \iff a = b & (6) & (\text{extensionality})\\
\{a\} \neq \{b\} & (7) & (\text{from premise, 6})\\
\{a\} = \{b,0\} \iff 0 \in \{a\} & (8) & (\text{extensionality})\\
\{a\} \neq \{b, 0\} & (9) & (\text{from premise, 8})\\
\perp & (10) & (\text{from 5, 7, 9})
\end{array}
$$

Any suggestions are very appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The direction $a=b\implies \{\{a\},\{a,0\}\}=\{\{b\},\{b,0\}\}$ is trivial.
For the other direction note that $\{\{a\},\{a,0\}\}=\{\{b\},\{b,0\}\}$ implies $\{a,0\}=\bigcup \{\{a\},\{a,0\}\}=\bigcup\{\{b\},\{b,0\}\}=\{b,0\}$, i.e.,
$(a=b\lor a=0)\land (0=b\lor 0=0)\land(b=a\lor b=0)\land (0=a\lor 0=0)$, which is readily equivalent to $a=b$.

Comment: thank you very much, I hadn't thought of using union!

Comment: I think you flipped some (read: all) of the $\land$ and $\lor$ there at the end.